# why do my basic commands output, but my embed command doesn't?

Tags: javascript, command, discord

I'm quite new to js, and i have been following a tutorial until now. I wanted to break away and create a command that would make an embedded message in discord (as an output). I have tried a few different ways, but none of the solutions seem to be working. When i run the command ?embed , nothing shows up, here is the if statement;

```
if(command === 'swept'){
       client.commands.get("swept").execute(message, args);
    } else if(command == 'youtube'){
        client.commands.get("youtube").execute(message, args);
    } else if (command == 'embed'){
        client.commands.get("embed").execute(message, args);
    }
})
```

The other two commands (?swept, ?youtube) work fine. Here is the piece of code that the command calls to for the embed;

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name: 'embed',
    description: "embed test if im not stupid",
    execute(message, args) {
        const embed =  new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Title')
            .addField('Field1', 'Field2')
            .addField('field 3', 'FiElD4')
            .setColor('#0aaaf5')
            message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

A solution or even an easier way to do it would be appreciated. The other two commands are coded the same way (in a separate file starting with module.exports = ...)

EDIT: Error message;

```
   const embed =  Discord.messageEmbeded()
                               ^

TypeError: Discord.messageEmbeded is not a function
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\alexh\Desktop\discord botting\commands\embed.js:8:32)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\alexh\Desktop\discord botting\main.js:33:38)     
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\alexh\Desktop\discord botting\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\alexh\Desktop\discord botting\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\alexh\Desktop\discord botting\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\alexh\Desktop\discord botting\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\alexh\Desktop\discord botting\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\alexh\Desktop\discord botting\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Comment: Have you an an error in console?

Comment: @RootMeIH , ill double check when i get out of school.

Comment: @RootMeIH C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\code\discord botting\commands\embed.js:5
        const embed =  new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                       ^

Comment: Add the error on your question

Comment: You added the place of the error, but not the error itself. Please add the stack trace

Comment: @DimaKuzmich i have edited the post and added the requested edits.

Comment: @animecabbage And I've answered your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not imported Discord.js lib in your file. Try to import it at the top of your file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
```

Then, the function for a discord embed is not `.messageEmbeded` but `.messageEmbed`.

Replace your line 8 by this:

```
const embed = new Discord.messageEmbed()
```

Comment: i still get this error message;

```
C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\code\discord botting\commands\embed.js:7
        const embed =  discord.messageEmbeded()
                       ^
```

Comment: That's not the entire error message, please edit your message with the complete error message + my modification

Answer (score 0):

Discord.JS is case sensitive. Meaning, uppercase and lowercase matter. So, it should be:

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you posted, you misspelled the command `Embed` and instead used `Embeded`.

Here is the error message you posted:

```js
const embed =  Discord.messageEmbeded()
                            ^
```

Try to change it in your code to:

```js
const embed = new Discord.messageEmbed()
```